# SoundCloud dynamic URL issue

Tags: php, json, iframe, soundcloud, oembed

I have a text file that contains a list of soundcloud track URLs. I also have a php file that randomly selects one of these URLs and allows me to receive it in a different php file. Now for some reason when I set $url as the randomly selected URL and call it in the next line. What I get is just the text version of the URL and not the iframe soundcloud embed code.

```
<?php

    //Get the SoundCloud URL
    $url = $_GET['type'] = 0; include 'http://example.com/randomselector.php';

    //Get the JSON data of song details with embed code from SoundCloud oEmbed
    $getValues=file_get_contents(
        'http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&url='.$url.'&iframe=true');               

    //Clean the Json to decode
    $decodeiFrame=substr($getValues, 1, -2);

    //json decode to convert it as an array
    $jsonObj = json_decode($decodeiFrame);

    //Change the height of the embed player if you want else uncomment below line
    echo $jsonObj->html;
?>
```

I have tried to manually insert a URL in the second line and that works properly. Meaning I get the iframe embed code.

**This is the randomselector.php**

```
    <?php

/* File, where the random text/quotes are stored one per line */
$settings['text_from_file'] = 'http://example.com/list.txt';

/*
   How to display the text?
   0 = raw mode: print the text as it is, when using RanTex as an include
   1 = Javascript mode: when using Javascript to display the quote
*/
$settings['display_type'] = 0;

/* Allow on-the-fly settings override? 0 = NO, 1 = YES */
$settings['allow_otf'] = 1;

/*******************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************/

/* Override type? */
if ($settings['allow_otf'] && isset($_GET['type']))
{
    $type = intval($_GET['type']);
}
else
{
    $type = $settings['display_type'];
}

/* Get a list of all text options */
if ($settings['text_from_file'])
{
    $settings['quotes'] = file($settings['text_from_file']);
}

/* If we have any text choose a random one, otherwise show 'No text to choose from' */
if (count($settings['quotes']))
{
    $txt = $settings['quotes'][array_rand($settings['quotes'])];
}
else
{
    $txr = 'No text to choose from';
}

/* Output the image according to the selected type */
if ($type)
{
    /* New lines will break Javascript, remove any and replace them with <br /> */
    $txt = nl2br(trim($txt));
    $txt = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),'',$txt);
    echo 'document.write(\''.addslashes($txt).'\')';
}
else
{
    echo $txt;
}
?>
```

**This is the list.txt**

```
Link1
Link2
Link3
```

Comment: To help you, pls share the randomselector.php / list file. You are totally right, i have added a line before file_get_contents - $url = link. It will work as expected. http://lab.sourcloud.com/stackoverflow/26092137/

Comment: I added the randomselector.php and list to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try curl insted of file_get_contents.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#oembed

See changes:

```
<?php

    //Get the SoundCloud URL
    $url = $_GET['type'] = 0; 
    include 'randomselector.php';

    $url = getUrl();

    $curlurl = 'http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=json&url='.$url;

    //curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$curlurl);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //sometimes you will get an error
//  $result = file_get_contents($curlurl);

    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    echo $result['html'];   
?>
```

randomselector.php

```
 <?php
function getUrl(){
/* File, where the random text/quotes are stored one per line */
$settings['text_from_file'] = 'list.txt';

/*
   How to display the text?
   0 = raw mode: print the text as it is, when using RanTex as an include
   1 = Javascript mode: when using Javascript to display the quote
*/
$settings['display_type'] = 0;

/* Allow on-the-fly settings override? 0 = NO, 1 = YES */
$settings['allow_otf'] = 1;

/*******************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************/

/* Override type? */
if ($settings['allow_otf'] && isset($_GET['type']))
{
    $type = intval($_GET['type']);
}
else
{
    $type = $settings['display_type'];
}

/* Get a list of all text options */
if ($settings['text_from_file'])
{
    $settings['quotes'] = file($settings['text_from_file']);
}

/* If we have any text choose a random one, otherwise show 'No text to choose from' */
if (count($settings['quotes']))
{
    $txt = $settings['quotes'][array_rand($settings['quotes'])];
}
else
{
    $txr = 'No text to choose from';
}

/* Output the image according to the selected type */
if ($type)
{
    /* New lines will break Javascript, remove any and replace them with <br /> */
    $txt = nl2br(trim($txt));
    $txt = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),'',$txt);
//    echo 'document.write(\''.addslashes($txt).'\')';
}
else
{
//    echo $txt;
}
return $txt;
}
?>
```

Comment: This works but how do I add auto_play and show_comments to this iframe? I did something like this:
`$curlurl = 'http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=json&url='.$url.'&auto_play=true&show_comments=false'`
But for somereason it only affects one of the URLs from the list.txt

Comment: Dont know what you mean by affects only one of the urls. http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=json&auto_play=true&show_comments=false&url= is working fine for me. Check here. http://lab.sourcloud.com/stackoverflow/26092137/